# Set up a password policy that has a maximum failed login attempts and a reset after a certain period of time

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, security, passwords

I asked this on the apple stack exchange site, but since the tumble weeds couldn't answer my question I will ask it here.

I tried using pwpolicy to set this up.  I was able to set up maxFailedLoginAttempts, but setting minutesUntilFailedLoginReset doesn't seem to do anything.  When I query pwpolicy using:

```
 pwpolicy -n /Local/Default -getglobalpolicy
```

I keep seeing that minutesUntilFailedLoginReset=0 even though I just set it to 60.  I even tried changing this for one user, and it claims it was changed but when I query the user's policy or the effective policy nothing has changed.

Comment: please see possible ideas at Apple SE.